# Run code in background even when app goes in background

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have written a code to execute in background as follows

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            for index in 1...50 {
                print("\(index)")
                usleep(1000000)
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print("done")
            }
        }
```

but when i press home and app goes to background code execution stops

How to to keep it running even when app goes in background

Comment: Short answer; you can't. There are specific background modes available on iOS for certain tasks. These are covered in the iOS application programming guide from Apple

Comment: i want to upload list of files serially in background even when app. How can i do this?? can answer for if or point me to some link??

Comment: Read more https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Comment: Also check this is specific to your need http://stackoverflow.com/a/23831862/5710872